# How to properly use recv function for TCP chat, python3?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Some sources say that *recv* should have the max length possible of a message, like ***recv(1024)***:

```py
message0 = str(client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

But other sources say that it should have the total bytes of the receiving message. If the message is "hello":

```py
message0 = str(client.recv(5).decode('utf-8'))
```

**What is the correct way of using recv()?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some sources say ... But other sources say ... message ...

Both sources are wrong.

The argument for the `recv` is the **maximum number of bytes one want to read at once**.

With an **UDP** socket this is the **message size** one want to read **or larger**, but a single `recv` will only return a single message anyway. If the given size is smaller than the message it will be pruned and the rest will be discarded.

With a **TCP** socket (the case you ask about) there is **no concept of a message in the first place** since TCP is a byte stream only. `recv` will simply return the **number of bytes available** for read, up to the given size. Specifically a single `recv` in a TCP receiver does not not need to match a single `send` in the sender. It might match and it often will match if the amount of data is small, but there is no guarantee and one should never rely on it.

> ... message0 = str(client.recv(5).decode('utf-8'))

Note that calling `decode('utf-8')` directly on the data returned by `recv` is a bad idea. One first need to be sure that all the expected data are read and only then  call `decode('utf-8')`. If only part of the data are read the end of the read data could be in the middle of a character, since a single character in UTF-8 might be encoded in multiple bytes (everything except ASCII characters). If `decode('utf-8')` is called with an incomplete encoded character it will throw an exception and your code will break.

Comment: Now I'm confused how does recv work, because both of my interpretations were wrong. Thank you, I'll search more about recv and how it works on TCP, because your answer (in a good way) was advanced for me.

Comment: @g_odim_3: Assuming that TCP has message semantics and deriving from this that a `recv` in the recipient matches a `send` in the sender, is unfortunately a very common error. The tragic is. that it often seems to work and then seemingly working code gets shipped. Which then fails unexpectedly for some customers and randomly (memory pressure, network instabilities, different MTU due to use of VPN ...) and nobody has a clue why.

Comment: It happened in my code. Where did you learn about sockets? It could help me to master the fundamentals of these functions and sockets in general.

Comment: @g_odim_3: *"Where did you learn about sockets?"* - nothing particular. Simply years of experience.